# What's the significance of the identifier in a Typescript index signature?

Tags: typescript

In Typescript I can define "dictionaries" (objects with arbitrary keys) using an "index signature":

```
type DictOfNumbers = {
    [foo: string]: number
};

let myDict: DictOfNumbers = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
}
```

In the example above, what does the word `foo` signify and how is it used when dealing with the `DictOfNumbers` type?

Comment: `what does the word foo signify` It's just for the benefit of any humans reading the code. So if you're making an object that maps userIds to numbers, then `[userId: string]: number` would be a good name. Or if you're mapping ice creams to numbers, then `[iceCreamId: string]: number` would be a good one.

Comment: It is just a dummy identifier and has no effect on assignability.  That is `{[k: string]: number}` and `{[fooBarBaz: string]: number}` are completely identical types.